Rails method fo cumulative sum of older items
A class Event has methods
def event_revenues
  event_sales.sum(&:sales_price)
end

  
def event_costs
  event_sales.sum(&:sales_cost) 
end
  
def event_contributions
  event_revenues - event_costs
end


and an attribute start_date.
How does one devise a method that cumulates all the event_contributions for events with start_date on or before self.start_date ?

What is your actual question? Are you looking for a way to this in Ruby or SQL?

Yes, I should have explicitely indicated Ruby.

Solution can be like
def event_contributions(something)
  relation = Event
  relation = relation.where('start_date < ?', something) if something
  relation.select('sum(sales_price - sales_cost) AS contribution').sum(&:contribution)
end


If what you want is a list of events and the totals per event you can do this in a much more performant way by letting the database do the bean counting instead of your Ruby spagetti code.
Event.group(:id)
     .left_joins(:event_sales)
     .select(
       '"events".*',
       'SUM("event_sales"."sales_price" - "event_sales"."sales_cost") AS event_contribution'
     )
     .where(
       created_at: ..date
     )

If what you want is actually just the aggregates and not model instances you can use ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum to get a hash:
Event.group(:id)
     .left_joins(:event_sales)
     .where(
       created_at: ..date
     )
     .sum(
       '"event_sales"."sales_price" - "event_sales"."sales_cost" AS event_contribution'
     )

The hash will use the Event id as the keys as that's the grouping.

You could go about it by defining a scope to gather the relevant events and then calling sum on the output from event_contributions.
scope :events_before_date(date), -> {
  self.where('start_date < ?', date)
}

# Then call
Event.events_before_date(<some date>).sum(:event_contributions)

